# Django: Map CreateView to an existing form template

Tags: python, html, django, forms, backend

I'm pretty new to Django and as an intern backend-developer, I'm asked to make a CreateView for a user to create a shop on the website. I need to make it so that it "maps" to a template my frontend colleague made, with all the fields and the styling already there.

I only know how to make simple CreateViews that basically generates a form for you. But here I don't want it to do that, I want to use the already existing styled fields in the template, but I'm having a hard time finding how to do that.

Here's my model (I haven't included all the lines for readability reasons, but I'll do if needed):

```
class Dealer(models.Model, CloneMixin):
    dealer_check = models.ForeignKey("self",null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    published = models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True, default=True)
    informed = models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True, default=False)
    objectid = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
    street = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
    number = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(editable=False,null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User,null=True,blank=True, related_name='dealers')
    isowner = models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True, default=False, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here's my form:

```
class ShopCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Dealer
        fields = ["name", "email", "phone", "street", "number", "description"]
```

And here's my view (You can probably ignore the get_context_data):

```
class ShopCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = "accounts/test_dealer_form.html"
    model = Dealer
    form_class = forms.ShopCreateForm
    success_url = "/"
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["website"] = Website.objects.first()
        return context
```

I haven't included the html template as it's pretty big and I think I only need to be shown a basic exemple of how it's done, but again I can include it if needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What problem/error are you facing?

Comment: I'm not facing errors, I just don't know how to do it. And I can't find the informations to help me do it.

Comment: Did you try changing the template_name to the react template?